# Use pandas between_time() function with list as input arguments

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I try to filter a data set in pandas to only get the data which fall within a list of specific time sections. I have the following data set on which I try to contain the data analysis:

[data csv](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ah4GTVTj4BDej5hqfxk-zBi9L_qHNw)

Further the begin and end times are taken as a column from the following .csv file:

[csv specifying time sections](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ah4GTVTj4BDej5hpJnzwRIPD2g9Pkg)

I made the following code but at the end I get a memory error since the list comprehensions are computational intensive. Does anybody know a better way to solve my problem?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

### Import python modules ###
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os
import xlsxwriter

### Needed Variables ###
timestep = 0.001

### Get current path ###
dirname = os.path.dirname(__file__)

### import the csv data and time sections file ###
df_data = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\ricks\OneDrive\Development\Tools\CGDAT\input_data\input_data.csv", header=0, encoding='utf-8')
df_data.columns = df_data.columns.str.title()         # Capitalize columns to prohibit key errors
df_data_time = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\ricks\OneDrive\Development\Tools\CGDAT\input_data\time_data.csv", header=0, encoding="utf-8", sep=';')
df_data_time.columns = df_data_time.columns.str.title()

### Create extra time column ###
df_data['Time'] = df_data['Timestamp']*timestep
df_data.index = pd.to_datetime(df_data['Time'], unit='s')

### Convert begin and start times to datetime format ###
begin_times = pd.to_datetime(df_data_time['Start Time'], format='%H:%M:%S.%f').dt.time
end_times = pd.to_datetime(df_data_time['End Time'], format='%H:%M:%S.%f').dt.time

### Get data within specific time ranges ###
# Begin time: List containing begin times [00:02:30, 00:07:30, ...]
# End times: List containing end times [00:05:00, 00:10:00, ...]
df_sections = [df_data.between_time(i, j) for i in begin_times for j in end_times]
df_result = pd.concat(df_sections) # Add all the df sections togheter
```

Comment: Instead of csv images, can you post sample data in the code itself. Helps folks to understand and if possible answer quickly!!

Comment: @RahulAgarwal Thanks I added a example file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem. The `out of memory` error was caused by the following line:

```
df_sections = [df_data.between_time(i, j) for i in begin_times for j in end_times]
```

The problem was that this code runs on all possible combinations of the `begin_times` and `end_times` lists while I only wanted to perform a row-wise comprehension. As a result, the right code should be.

```
df_sections = [df_data.between_time(i, j) for (i,j) in zip(begin_times, end_times)]
```

#### Working  code example

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

### Import python modules ###
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os
import xlsxwriter

### Needed Variables ###
timestep = 0.001

### Get current path ###
dirname = os.path.dirname(__file__)

### import the csv data and time sections file ###
df_data = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\ricks\OneDrive\Development\Tools\CGDAT\input_data\input_data.csv", header=0, encoding='utf-8')
df_data.columns = df_data.columns.str.title()         # Capitalize columns to prohibit key errors
df_data_time = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\ricks\OneDrive\Development\Tools\CGDAT\input_data\time_data.csv", header=0, encoding="utf-8", sep=';')
df_data_time.columns = df_data_time.columns.str.title()

### Create extra time column ###
df_data['Time'] = df_data['Timestamp']*timestep
df_data.index = pd.to_datetime(df_data['Time'], unit='s')

### Convert begin and start times to datetime format ###
begin_times = pd.to_datetime(df_data_time['Start Time'], format='%H:%M:%S.%f').dt.time
end_times = pd.to_datetime(df_data_time['End Time'], format='%H:%M:%S.%f').dt.time

### Get data within specific time ranges ###
# Begin time: List containing begin times [00:02:30, 00:07:30, ...]
# End times: List containing end times [00:05:00, 00:10:00, ...]
df_sections = [df_data.between_time(i, j) for (i,j) in zip(begin_times, end_times)]
df_result = pd.concat(df_sections) # Add all the df sections togheter
```